# Overflow and list style type doesn't work

Tags: html, css

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.test {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Without * list style type is shown. How to show list-style-type with overflow and * style?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hcFCs/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add padding-left to `test` class. Try this:

**html:**

```
<div class="test">
    <ul>
        <li>description</li>
        <li>description</li>
        <li>description</li>
        <li>description</li>
        <li>description</li>
        <li>description</li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

**css:**

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.test {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcFCs/2/)

Answer (score 0):

please add margin-left on li tag to make list visible

```
.test ul li {
    margin-left:20px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hcFCs/3/)

```
ul{margin-left:20px;}
.test {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution could be adding: list-style-position: inside;

Support: [Can I Use - all browsers (since IE6+, Firefox 2+, Chrome 1+ etc)](https://caniuse.com/#search=list-style-position)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.test {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <ul>
    <li>description</li>
    <li>description</li>
    <li>description</li>
    <li>description</li>
    <li>description</li>
    <li>description</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```